# Using Amazon MechanicalTurk if location is not US?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

[Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) is a mass-micro outsourcing API, where you can get lots's of small simple tasks (e.g."Is there a shop in this image") done relatively cheaply (e.g. 0.10 U$ per image).

Amazon seems to assume that this service is mostly of interest to US companies. This results in difficulties if you want to use the service (as an "Requester"): for example there is no easy way of funding your Account without an US Bank account.

Can somebody share experiences of using the Service from outside the US?

Comment: Is this still the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Amazon [doesn't let outside US access yet](http://aws.amazon.com/mturk/faqs/#Can_international_Requesters_use_Amazon_Mechanical_Turk_to_get_tasks_completed), you'll need to either:

- Wait for Amazon to open it up to outside US, might be a long wait.
- Get a good friend in the US to open a PO Box for you then use an online US bank to create an account. If you don't start a corporation or other legal business, they will need to provide their US drivers license to Amazon too.
- Use a 3rd party provider like [HIT-Builder](http://www.hit-builder.com/) who will let you post on Mechanical Turk using their US Amazon account.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My Google-Foo seems to leave me there - how do I find additional 3rd party providers like HIT-Builder?

Comment: Actually they were the only ones I know of that currently have that service available to those outside the country.

Comment: I now used HIP-Builder and I'm quite happy with them so far.

Comment: That is good to hear. How were the costs compared to what you would expect using Mechanical Turk directly?

Comment: http://www.hit-builder.com/ is closed now... Anyone knows of any other alternatives?

Comment: You can try [TurkPrime Labs](https://www.turkprime.com/labs). They will run HITs for non-US based researchers

Answer (score 2):

I think they recently changed their rules - I am based in Australia, and as recently as 6 months ago I was unable to use Mechanical Turk. That recently changed and now I am able to post jobs on the service.

Comment: How? When I try to register it says "At this time Mechanical Turk does not support Requesters from countries outside the United States."

Comment: Same they said to me. not available outside US.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [TurkPrime labs](https://www.turkprime.com/labs) which offers this as a service to non-US based researchers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that to actually be able to add funds to your account, you need to have a US billing address. If you can get round that issue, then it all works fine.