# Amazon Mechanical Turk HIT Request from outside the US?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I would like to *request* an MTurk HIT task from outside the US. Currently, when I try to register I see my country auto registered as US with the following information :

> Why is the country set as United
>   States? At this time Mechanical Turk
>   does not support Requesters from
>   countries outside the United States

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091059/required-fields-in-mechanical-turk) solution but I am looking for other alternatives (using MTurk itself).

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478426/using-amazon-mechanicalturk-if-location-us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a US postal address and bank account to "register".

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd call out that MTurk now supports Requesters outside of the United States (as of 10/18/2016, it's US, CA, GB, and AU).

More info can be found here: https://blog.mturk.com/weve-made-it-easier-for-more-requesters-to-use-amazon-mechanical-turk-ab2ae649c555#.cevqbda64